# To save screenshots of each execution in different folder in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

For each execution screenshots should be saved in different folder with date and time. Tried with below code but its not working as expected.It is generating folder based on minutes not on Execution.Please help..Thanks in advance.

```
public static String screenShot(WebDriver driver,
        String screenShotName, String testName) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd_MM_yyyy_hh_mm_ss");
    SimpleDateFormat formater1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd_MM_yyyy_hh_mm");
    try {
File screenshotFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        File targetFile = new File("iWealthHKTestAutomation/resources/Screenshots_"+formater1.format(calendar.getTime())+"/"+ screenShotName+formater1.format(calendar.getTime()) + ".png");
        FileUtils.copyFile(screenshotFile, targetFile);

        return screenShotName;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("An exception occured while taking screenshot " + e.getCause());
        return null;
    }

}

public String getTestClassName(String testName) {
    String[] reqTestClassname = testName.split("\\.");
    int i = reqTestClassname.length - 1;
    System.out.println("Required Test Name : " + reqTestClassname[i]);
    return reqTestClassname[i];
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isiDu.png)

Comment: how u r calling the screenshot method?

Comment: Hi Vikas, Thanks for the response.      
    This is how i call the function.GenericFunctions.screenShot(getDriver(), "Username", "");                                                                                                     The above code creates a folder for each minute but i need for each execution.

Comment: You are using the timestamp in the folder names. Shouldn't you be using testName for the folder and timestamp for the filenames?

Comment: will u please share the code form where( which Class) u r calling the screenShot() Function.

Comment: @rakshitha - The comment of KDM is correct if you append testName in folderName and timestamp in screenshot name then it will give desired output. Using timestamp in name of will generate new folders even if you call it for same test again and again because seconds will change so every time new folder will be created...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you call screenShot multiple times during one "run". So if you want the folder to have the "execution time" or rather the start time of the run, you have to pass that as a parameter as well. Otherwise screenShot() will always create a new timestamp.
So change the signature to

```
public static String screenShot(WebDriver driver,
    String screenShotName, String testName, Date startTime) {...
```

and use startTime instead of the Calendar object.

Comment: Thank you so much, It worked. But ,i want for each iteration of for loop ,the screenshots should be saved in different folder.                                                                                  
       public boolean place_order_form() throws Throwable {
  int count = ExcelUtil.rowCount;
  for(int i=1;i<=count;i++) {
  String refID=ExcelUtil.getCellData("Ref_ID",i);
  placeOrder.FluentWait(placeOrder.verifyPlaceOrderPage);
  GenericFunctions.screenShot(getDriver(),"POPage" , "",startTime); 
    
  }

Answer (score 0):

You have to add testname in folder as it will track execution

If you use timestamp then it will change for same test also

```
public static String screenShot(WebDriver driver,String screenShotName, String 
      testName) {
        try {
        File screenshotFile = ((TakesScreenshot) 
        driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        File targetFile = 
            new File("iWealthHKTestAutomation/resources/Screenshots_"
                + testName /* pass testname param here like this*/
                + "/"
                + screenShotName
                + String.valueOf(new 
                 SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss").format(new Date())) 
                + ".png");
        FileUtils.copyFile(screenshotFile, targetFile);
        return screenShotName;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("An exception occured while taking screenshot " + e.getCause());
        return null;
    }

}
```